# Receiving RPC error using GWT, Tomcat and Apache

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, gwt, webserver

I am running a web server with the following configuration:

- PHP Website running on Apache (port 80) (www.MyWebsite.com)
- GWT Web Application running on Tomcat (port 8080) with a different URL (www.MyWebapp.com)
- Web service also running on Tomcat (port 8080) with subdomain (service.MyWebapp.com)

I am struggling with some configuration issues. I am able to access the website as well as the web service with my current configuration, but for some reason my web application is throwing an RPC error when I access it remotely through the URL.

My vhosts.conf file is as follows:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName MyWebapp.com   
ServerAlias www.MyWebapp.com
ProxyRequests off
DefaultType text/html
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/webapp/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/webapp/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName service.mywebapp.com        
DefaultType text/html
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/webservice/    
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/webservice/    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mywebsite.com
ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/website"
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/website/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to access it remotely via www.mywebapp.com, I get the HTML landing page, but when I make any RPC calls I receive an RPC error:

```
Type 'com.mycom.client.utility.model.DataContainer' was not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' and did not have a custom field serializer. For security purposes, this type will not be deserialized.
```

I can access and run my web application locally (localhost:8080/webapp), as well as remotely if I specify the port (www.MyWebapp.com:8080/webapp), and do not receive any RPC errors.

My 'DataContainer' class implements java.io.Serializable, not com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable (I've never encountered an issue with this before). I am under the impression that this has more to do with proxy settings than serialization, but have tried everything I can think of without success.

Any help would be much appreciated!!! Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are You able to add `IsSerializable` interface to `DataContainer` class and check if it works? I don't think this is related to proxy settings.

Comment: Might be a SOP-problem.